# Count number of groups present in column using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table as shown below:

```
create table test
(
  cola varchar(10) 
)
```

Inserting some data:

```
insert into test values('a');
insert into test values('a');
insert into test values('a');
insert into test values('b');
insert into test values('b');
insert into test values('c');
insert into test values('d');
insert into test values('d');
```

I want to show how many groups are present in the column `cola`

Expected Result:

```
TotalGroups   a    b    c    d 
--------------------------------
 4            3    2    1    2
```

Comment: Search for "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yes! you are right. Can you please tell me how to `count` `totalGroups`?

Comment: `select count(distinct cola) from test`.

Comment: problem is that you need to know which values is in cola in order to set up the pivot

Comment: @t-clausen.dk that is why Gordon said to search for "dynamic pivot".

Comment: Yes! I got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, removing [ and ] to avoid sql injections:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 
       'SELECT (select count(distinct cola) from test) TotalGroups'

SELECT @sql += ',' +cast(count(*) as varchar(10)) + 
      '['+ replace(replace(cola, ']', ''), '[', '') + ']'
FROM TEST
GROUP BY cola
ORDER BY cola


EXEC(@sql)
```

Result:

```
Total_Groups  a  b  c  d
4             3  2  1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT count(distinct cola) AS Total_Groups, COUNT(CASE WHEN COLA = 'a' THEN 1 END) AS a,
                                             COUNT(CASE WHEN COLA = 'b' THEN 1 END) AS b,
                                             COUNT(CASE WHEN COLA = 'c' THEN 1 END) AS c,
                                             COUNT(CASE WHEN COLA = 'd' THEN 1 END) AS d                   
FROM TEST;
```

Here is the Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe5be/19

Comment: Then sure and certainly he/she has to use dynamic pivot query as said by @Gordon Linoff. But this is suitable sol. for the given scenario.